# comparing 2 tuples in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

Based on the following dataframe:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
test_list = ['purple', 'red', 'yellow']
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'colors': [['red','blue'], ['white'], ['blue','yellow']]})
df['colors_new'] = df.colors.map(tuple)
```

I am trying to generate a new column where if at least one of the elements in test_list is in each row then I mark that row as true

```
df['found'] = any((True for x in test_list if x in df['colors_new']))
df
```

[image: Sample_response]

in the example above row 0 and 2 should be true, because red is in row 0 and yellow is in row 2

which will be the most efficient and correct way as I am currently getting the wrong results

I think the closest that I am able to get a right response is

```
df['found'] = ['red' in x for x in df['colors_new']]
```

But using this doesnt work when I have multiple items (test_list = ['purple', 'red', 'yellow'])

[image]

Comment: You can use sets and intersections instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### using explode

```
df['found'] = df['colors_new'].explode().isin(test_list).groupby(level=0).max()
```

output:

```
   numbers          colors      colors_new  found
0        1     [red, blue]     (red, blue)   True
1        2         [white]        (white,)  False
2        3  [blue, yellow]  (blue, yellow)   True
```

##### using python sets

You could use a set and `set.intersection`, if the intersection is not empty, there are common values.

Sets operations are faster than classical loops.

```
test_list = set(test_list)
df['found'] = df['colors_new'].apply(lambda x: len(test_list.intersection(x))>0)
```

output:

```
   numbers          colors      colors_new  found
0        1     [red, blue]     (red, blue)   True
1        2         [white]        (white,)  False
2        3  [blue, yellow]  (blue, yellow)   True
```

*NB. as a bonus you can use the same approach to get the found elements*

```
df['found elements'] = df['colors_new'].apply(test_list.intersection)
```

output:

```
   numbers          colors      colors_new  found found elements
0        1     [red, blue]     (red, blue)   True          {red}
1        2         [white]        (white,)  False             {}
2        3  [blue, yellow]  (blue, yellow)   True       {yellow}
```

Comment: Hi Is there a way of voiding using apply I had a different approach that was working but it was quite slow, as I had thousands of rows and several columns to calculates in a similar fashion

Comment: @Manza sure, check update

Comment: will be correct to asume that explode() will be the fastest?

Comment: @Manza - added test performance to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use sets with `isdisjoint` if performance is important:

```
s = set(test_list)
df['colors_new'] = ~df.colors.map(s.isdisjoint)
```

Or:

```
s = set(test_list)
df['colors_new'] = df['colors'].map(s.intersection).astype(bool)

print (df)

   numbers          colors  colors_new
0        1     [red, blue]        True
1        2         [white]       False
2        3  [blue, yellow]        True
```

**Performance** in test data, best test in real, because depends of length of DataFrame, length of tested list, number of matched values:

```
df['colors_new'] = df.colors.map(tuple)

#3k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

test_list = ['purple', 'red', 'yellow']

s = set(test_list)

In [46]: %timeit df['colors_new'] = ~df.colors.map(s.isdisjoint)
707 µs ± 20.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [47]: %timeit df['colors_new'] = df['colors'].map(s.intersection).astype(bool)
1.38 ms ± 153 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [50]: %timeit df['found'] = df['colors_new'].apply(lambda x: len(s.intersection(x))>0)
1.68 ms ± 42.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [51]: %timeit df['found'] = df['colors_new'].explode().isin(test_list).groupby(level=0).max()
4.66 ms ± 166 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [52]: %timeit df['found'] = df['colors_new'].apply(lambda x: bool(max([1 if y in test_list else 0 for y in x])))
2.91 ms ± 118 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [54]: %timeit df["colors_map"] = df[['colors','colors_new']].apply(lambda x:any([x2 in test_list for x1 in x for x2 in x1]), axis=1)
26.1 ms ± 1.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `lambda` function to get what you want:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
test_list = ['purple', 'red', 'yellow']
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'colors': [['red','blue'], ['white'], ['blue','yellow']]})
df['colors_new'] = df.colors.map(tuple)

df['found'] = df['colors_new'].apply(lambda x: bool(max([1 if y in test_list else 0 for y in x])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions as well:

```
df["colors_map"] = df[['colors','colors_new']].apply(lambda x:any([x2 in test_list for x1 in x for x2 in x1]), axis=1)
```

If you have a lot of `colors` colums you are checking (not just 2):

```
df["colors_map"] = df[[x for x in df.columns if "colors" in x]].apply(lambda x:any([x2 in test_list for x1 in x for x2 in x1]), axis=1)
```